# How to make a post write the current user as the author?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have some problems with my blog I appreciate it if you'd help me with them if I need to add any other codes please let me know

1- when I login as different users and write a post it always mentions only one of my accounts as the author it doesn't write the current user's username as the author and I can see and delete all the other users posts when I login with only one of the accounts and when I add an author part to my forms the box let me choose from all my accounts I want the current logged in user to be mentioned as the author

also when I write a post the spaces between the lines and all that is correct but when I post it it all just  displays beneath each other with no space between the lines

detail.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}

<html>
  <div style="margin-top: 20px"></div>
  <body class="text-center" style="line-height: 2;">
    <article>
      <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
      <p style="margin-top: 15px;">{{post.body}}</p>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>

{% endblock %}
```

post.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="margin-top: 25px"></div>
    <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
        <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">{{post.title}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
        {{ post.body|truncatewords_html:30 }}
        <hr>
        <p><img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" width="75" height="75"> Author: {{ post.author }}</p>
        <a href="{% url 'detail' post.id %}" class="btn btn-info btn-small" >Read More <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-three-dots" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M3 9.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3z"/>
          </svg></a>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" id="deleteButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6Z"/>
            <path d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1ZM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118ZM2.5 3h11V2h-11v1Z"/>
          </svg></a>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap Delete Confirmation Modal</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <div class="icon-box">
          </div>                
          <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>    
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p  class="text-muted">Do you really want to delete these records? This process cannot be undone.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete' post.id %}">Delete</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>     
  </body>
  </html>
</div>
```

new.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}



<form method="post">
  <style>
    textarea {
  resize: none;
}
  </style>
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div style="margin-top: 15px"></div>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Create Post</legend>
          {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
       
        <div class="form-group">
          <div style="margin-top: 20px"></div>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create</button>
      </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from .models import post



class postform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = post
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('author',)
        widgets = {
            'body': Textarea()
        }
```

Comment: where do you write to database? In database you should add current user as author. And later you should check if this post belong to current user when you want to edit or delete post. I don't see this part of code. HTML is not so important for this.

Comment: share the view that works with the `potform`.

Answer (score 0):

You assign it in the view, so if this is a `CreateView`, you wok with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import CreateView


class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'new.html'
    form_class = PostForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

> **Note**: Forms in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`postform`</s> to `PostForm`.